# Can I use SMOTE technique to increase the number of observations in forecasting problem?

Tags: regression, forecasting, references, oversampling, smote

I have done my thesis on forecasting problem in advertisment industry. However, it resulted that the prediction accuracy for traditional econometric models (Lasso, Ridge) showed the better results rather than ML models. The reason that we came up is the number of observations. I have 169 observations.
Now I want to investigate this hypothesis by increasing the number of the observations with over-sampling method. Do you know any relevant paper published about this and do you think this method could work, if not why?

Comment: No. One cannot magically create tabular data for free. The generated data will be dependent on the observed one. Correcting for this dependency is difficult.

Comment: @MichaelM thank you for the response. For sure, I want to keep the characteristics of the observed data. The study that I want to do is to prove that ML models after oversampling are working better.

Comment: They are not. You'd better show that there is no advantage of these techniques.

Comment: SMOTE is a "gift" that keeps on giving.  How this ever got to be accepted in any field is amazing to me.  This reminds of a paper I was sent to review where the writer said that you could expand any sample size using the bootstrap so large sample sizes are never needed.

Comment: @FrankHarrell  thank you all for your comments! I was thinking that the simple comparison of the Econometric Models and ML models would not be enough for a pubblication. (it's my first experience) . That's why I was thinking to use SMOTE. 
I wonder if anyone could help me understand whether my thesis can be a canddate for a pubblication? My thesis compares Econometric and ML models' predictive performance and that's all.

Comment: All I can give is overall advice of using proper accuracy scoring rules (never proportional "classified" "correctly") and use resampling methods to estimate proper accuracy scores accounting for overfitting.  See also [this](https://fharrell.com/post/addvalue).